# View all calendars in exchange 2003

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2003

I wanted to know how I could give a user access to view all calendars in Exchange 2003 without having to ask for access from all my users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign full access permissions on the mailbox store. This will allow you to access any information not only calendars. There is no way assign permissions to calendars only this way, only all or nothing.